# ASP.NET show div on button click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

am trying to show a loading div on button click, but it is not working at the moment.

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {      
            $('#BtnSend').click(function () {
                $('#<%= loading.ClientID %>').toggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Div:

```
<div id="loading" class="Loading" runat="server" visible="false">
  <div class="loadingImg">
    <img src="../Images/loading.gif" alt="loading" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSend" runat="server" Text="SEND" 
            onclick="BtnSend_Click" CssClass="pressbutton2" Height="36px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

the div is set to runat server so that I can change its visibility also through code.

Comment: Have you considered using a jQuery plugin like [BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)?

Comment: Did you check whether in the HTML generated by ASP.NET, the button retains the ID specified in the aspx file? I am 100% sure that the ID you see in the file is not the same one it'll have in the page when the button is part of a custom user control.

Comment: Note: The ID is a server control is *not* [usually] the same as the ClientID. The ClientID (aka DOM ID) uses the control ID, the control hierarchy, and mapping rules to create the derived ClientID.

Comment: from both sides for validation in case javascript is turned off

Comment: Do you want to do this server or client side? If you want client side you need to not use the `onClick` because it will look in the code behind for the function and run that; instead use `onClientClick` and make your jquery a function with a name and call the name. If you do want server side, please show us the server side code.

Comment: You got onclick="BtnSend_Click" which means there is a postback. Does you page refreshes when you click the button?

Comment: yes it does. is this why my div is not being shown?

Comment: with the postback it is going to your code behind for the function, what is the code in the function you created in the code behind?

Comment: just a test button for now that doesnt do anything

Comment: Do you have any code within BtnSend_Click event block?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `onClientClick` for the asp button. Then make the jquery function that you ahve called `BtnSend_Click`

If you want to do it via Client side:

jQuery

```
function BtnSend_Click () {
     $('#<%= loading.ClientID %>').toggle("slow");
}
```

ASP Button

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSend" runat="server" Text="SEND" 
            onClientClick="BtnSend_Click" CssClass="pressbutton2" Height="36px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

If you want to do it via the server:

C#

```
protected void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     loading.Visibility = 'visible' //not sure on syntax to show it in code behind off the top my head
}
```

ASP Button

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSend" runat="server" Text="SEND" 
            onClick="BtnSend_Click" CssClass="pressbutton2" Height="36px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried adding in a prevent default, as the code as described below would postback before the loading div was shown otherwise.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {      
        $('#<%= BtnSend.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#<%= loading.ClientID %>').toggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another thing I've noticed is you have set `Visible="false"`:

```
<div id="loading" class="Loading" runat="server" visible="false">
```

This means the div doesn't exist as its not output from the server side. Look in the view source when the page loads, it wont be there and hidden, its just not there. Remove the `visible="false"` and use CSS to hide it to start off with.

Comment: its just a css class to customise the div. still not working though.

Comment: oh i see now, you did ClientID for the div but not the button! Updating snippet

Comment: actually you have ClientIDMode static so its probably not that, but the visible false issue.

Comment: which one are you referring to?

Comment: was refering to your clientID which was set to static. 

I removed the visible="false" and set style="display:none;" but div still not shown when button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.Net AJAX library has an `UpdateProgress` control that sounds like it would fit your needs.