# How to show or hide webchart by click a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I want to learn show and hide a  webchart by when click checkbox in asp.net.

```
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="check1" runat="server" 
 OnCheckedChanged="check1_CheckedChanged" 
 Text="Fill Details" CheckState="Unchecked" >
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>

<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="check2" runat="server"  
   OnCheckedChanged="check2_CheckedChanged" ,     
   Text="Sales Details">
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

And I have 2 webchart

```
<dx:WebChartControl ID="FillDetails" runat="server" CrosshairEnabled="True" Height="600px" Width="900px"></dx:WebChartControl>

<dx:WebChartControl ID="SalesDetails" runat="server" CrosshairEnabled="True" Height="600px" Width="900px"></dx:WebChartControl>
```

I am not good about javascript.I want show FillDetails webchart when I click checkbox1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796786/asp-net-show-div-on-button-click

Answer (score 0):

you can set FillDetails display to 'none' and then use this :

```
<script>
    function changeVisibility() {
        $('#' + '<%= FillDetails.ClientID %>').css({ display: 'block' });
    };

</script>
```

and your CheckBox:

```
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="check1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="changeVisibility();" Text="Fill Details" CheckState="Unchecked" >
```